# Binding to custom event in child iframe?

Tags: jquery

I have a child iframe on the page with the id #editor_frame. Inside the iframe is a small jquery widget (not a jquery ui-widget from widget factory) which fires a simple 'change' event after some user interaction.

I'm trying to bind to that event from the parent page...

```
$('#editor_iframe').contents().find('#uielement').bind('change', function(){....});
```

With no luck what so ever. After doing some hair pulling research, I guess that events in the iframe are bound to the jquery namespace inside the that window... If that is correct, how can I access the jquery namespace in the iframe window?

Any takers?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can access the javascript in a child iframe from the parent in the following way:

```
document.getElementById('editor_iframe').contentWindow.yourfunction()
```

Likewise, since jquery is just a function, you can access the iframe jquery instance like this:

```
document.getElementById('editor_iframe').contentWindow.$(yourjquery)...
```

Comment: could you explain how you replaced the binding to that event.

Comment: Please explain how to actually do the binding though.

Answer (score 0):

Erik, I ran into the similar problem today.

What I found was that my javascript function ran before the iframe even completed loaded.
Try this:

```
$('#editor_iframe').load(function() {
  $(this)
    .contents()
    .find('#uielement')
    .bind('change', function() {
        //  do stuff
    });
});
```

Comment: appreciate the reply, but my binding is already inside the load function like you've mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue but the solutions provided thus far don't solve it for me. It seems to me that the existing solutions don't directly answer the question. So here's my solution.

**Restating the issue:** In a parent page I want to listen for an event that the child page triggers.

**Solution:** The key to solving this mystery is to realize that instances of jQuery running in a particular window are isolated from each other. So when you trigger an event in the child, only the child's instance of jQuery can listen for it. The solution is to add a listener to the child window that calls a function in the parent window.

**Triggering an event in the child page:**

```
$(document).trigger("myCustomEvent");
```

**Event handler code in the parent page:**

```
var $iframe = $("#theIframe");

// Wait for the iframe to finish loading...
$iframe.on("load", function () {
    // Bind an event handler to the iframe's instance of jQuery, listening for the event called "myCustomEvent".
    $iframe[0].contentWindow.$($iframe[0].contentWindow.document).on("myCustomEvent", function () {
        // The code in that you put into this anonymous function resides in and will
        // run in the context of the parent page.
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest using [postMessage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage) to communicate between the parent and child. It's safer and more reliable.